# Changing a variable based on a user's input

Tags: ruby

I am trying to have `xpos` and `ypos` change based on the direction the player enters. The program succeeds in asking `Where to?` but the position does not change. The script also always defaults to the last condition `(puts("You're drunk."))`.

For example:

```
> n
0
1
```

However, my output is:

```
> n
You're drunk.
0
0
```

---

This is my current code:

```rb
north = "n"
west = "w"
south = "s"
east = "e"
xpos = 0
ypos = 0

puts("WHERE TO?")
compass = gets

if compass == north
    ypos = ypos + 1
elseif compass == west
    xpos = xpos - 1
elseif compass == south
    ypos = ypos - 1
elseif compass == east
    xpos = xpos + 1
else
    puts("You're drunk.") #if the player does not submit a proper direction

    puts(xpos) #for debugging. prints zero when called showing the player has not moved
    puts(ypos)
end
```

Comment: Just a small side comment -- in Ruby, you don't always need the parentheses around function arguments. For examples, most of your `puts(...)` here can become `puts ...`. I've noticed that this seems to the the Ruby way to do things, though your code is still correct.

Comment: You forgot to `chomp!` your input.

Comment: Another side note: It's `elsif`, not `elseif`, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two main issues, at least that I can see. First, `elseif` should be `elsif`. I'm surprised you aren't getting a syntax error on that.

Second, [`Kernel::gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) returns the next line entered, up to *and including* the linebreak. This means that you have to remove the linebreak at the end, so that comparing with strings that don't have `\r\n` or `\n`, depending on your platform, can be compared. This is very simple: Just replace

```
compass = gets
```

with

```
compass = gets.chomp
```

([`String#chomp` reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp))

Alternatively, if you'd like to get rid of all whitespace before and after, you could use

```
compass = gets.strip
```

([`String#strip` reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-strip))

Comment: It's best to use `chomp` in this situation since it will only remove the record   separator in the case that the user wants to keep white space.

Comment: @squiguy It depends on the case. For example, if OP wants to make sure that even accidental spaces don't influence which option is selected, then strip is best. However, if he wants whitespace, then yes, chomp is best.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it's probably the missing `chomp` and the `elseif`.

Just a suggestion, but this cries out for a `case` statement:

```
case compass
  when 'north'
    ypos = ypos + 1
  when 'west'
    xpos = xpos - 1
  when 'south'
   ypos = ypos - 1
  when 'east'
   xpos = xpos + 1
 else
  puts("You're drunk.") #if the player does not submit a proper direction
  puts(xpos)#for debugging. prints zero when called showing the player has not moved
  puts(ypos)
end
```